# what is happening on os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, botframework

I am creating a bot using botframework within a django application.
At first, I was not able to call the models of that application from the bot. I found a solution, which was to put `os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = True` in the settings.py file.

It works fine for me.

But I am curious to know, what is happening when I do this. Is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` to `true` is not a recommended way. It may cause data loss. So, I changed the function as an API end-point and called it, instead of calling the function. It works for me.

Comment: can you explain why or were you found this info?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you are allowing the django project to run asynchronously using the asyncio module and the async keyword.